# given a list of numbers, find the first and last times a certain number is entered

Tags: c, scanf

I need to create a program that, when the user inputs a list of integers, finds the position of the first and last entry of that number, and the number of times that specific number shows up.

The proper output is supposed to look like this:

```
Enter a number to find: 4
Enter a list of numbers (negative to quit): 1 8 4 9 3 4 4 8 2 4 10 3 4 2 4 -1
This list contains 15 numbers.
First occurrence of '4': 3
Last occurrence of '4': 15
Quite a few were found!
```

I have it working great except for one thing: since I'm using scanf to take in the user input each time, instead of putting all the numbers on one line, like this:

```
1 8 4 9 3 4 4 8 2 4 10 3 4 2 4 -1
```

it does this:

```
1
8
4
9
3
4
4
```

etc.

Is there any way to have it *not* start a new line with each entry?

Comment: It's up to user now, probably. Just write all of them on one line and it should work.

Comment: It should be fine to just read them one at a time even if all entered on the same line separated by whitespace. [See it live](http://ideone.com/yLYgHx) for a super-simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, if you use `\n` in your `printf` format string, it will do a new line.  If you don't have that character in there, it won't.  So take it out and write a new line *after* your loop.

Likewise, when you are entering your numbers at the prompt, don't press *enter* after each one.  It looks like you are supposed to enter them separated by spaces.

Given that you want to display the prompt text on the same line as the input, you may need to flush output too:

```
printf( "Enter a list of numbers (negative to quit): " );
fflush( stdout );

// Input loop.
int num;
do {
    if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &num ) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Bad input\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    // Do something with the input...

} while( num != -1 );
```

Comment: Well this shows my ignorance in programming. You're absolutely right, the user is just supposed to enter everything in on the same line. It works perfectly. My mistake, thank you for the help.